# Why does Iterator::take_while take ownership of the iterator?

Tags: rust

I find it odd that [`Iterator::take_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) takes ownership of the iterator. It seems like a useful feature to be able to take the first *x* elements which satisfy some function but still leave the rest of the elements available in the original iterator.

I understand that this is incompatible with a lazy implementation of `take_while`, but still feels useful. Was this just judged not useful enough to include in the standard library, or is there some other problem I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

All the iterator adapters take the original iterator by value for efficiency's sake. Additionally, taking ownership of the original iterator avoids having to deal with lifetimes when it isn't necessary.

If you wish to retain access to the original iterator, you can use [`by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref). This introduces one level of indirection, but the programmer chooses to opt into the extra work when the feature is needed:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let mut i1 = v.iter();
    for z in i1.by_ref().take_while(|&&v| v < 4) {
        //     ^^^^^^^^^
        println!("Take While: {}", z);
    }

    for z in i1 {
        println!("Rest: {}", z);
    }
}
```

Has the output

```
Take While: 1
Take While: 2
Take While: 3
Rest: 5
Rest: 6
Rest: 7
Rest: 8
```

`Iterator::by_ref` works because there's an implementation of `Iterator` for any mutable reference to an iterator:

```rust
impl<'_, I> Iterator for &'_ mut I
where
    I: Iterator + ?Sized,
```

This means that you can also take a mutable reference. The parenthesis are needed for precedence:

```rust
for z in (&mut i1).take_while(|&&v| v < 4)
```

---

Did you note that `4` was missing? That's because once `take_while` picks a value and decides to not use it, there's nowhere for it to "put it back". Putting it back would require opting into *more* storage and slowness than is always needed.

I've used the [itertools crate](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/) to handle cases like this, specifically [`take_while_ref`](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.take_while_ref):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.9.0

fn main() {
    let v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let mut i1 = v.iter();
    for z in i1.take_while_ref(|&&v| v < 4) {
        //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        println!("Take While: {}", z);
    }

    for z in i1 {
        println!("Rest: {}", z);
    }
}
```

```
Take While: 1
Take While: 2
Take While: 3
Rest: 4
Rest: 5
Rest: 6
Rest: 7
Rest: 8
```

Comment: Is there a syntax sugar to `by_ref`?  This API isn't very friendly.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I'd say that _is_ the nice form. You can also do `(&mut i1).take_while(...)`

Comment: Eh, better.  The documentation wasn't super clear about the ownership part (probably just inexperience speaking here), so this answer and response are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If it's getting too complicated, we may be using the wrong tool.
Note that 4 is present here.

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let mut i1 = v.iter().peekable();
    while let Some(z) = i1.next_if(|&n| n < &4) {
        println!("Take While: {z}");
    }
    for z in i1 {
        println!("Rest: {z}");
    }
}
```

```
Take While: 1
Take While: 2
Take While: 3
Rest: 4
Rest: 5
Rest: 6
Rest: 7
Rest: 8
```

`next_if` *is called on each element of the iterator*

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=cf0a80c8de2639d118fc68e0942b6c04)
Yes, the OP asked for `take_while` and [Shepmaster's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31374079/155423) is superb.