# Desire to iterate over two word list files in Rust

Tags: rust

Currently, regardless of the different attempts that I have tried. I cannot pass the wordlist words from both iterations to a new thread.

I am attempting to build a web application fuzzing tool, and I want the ability to use at least two different wordlists at the same time, like other popular fuzzing tools can do. However, I run into errors attempting to do so in Rust.

My guess is its because by the second-pass on the second list the items have already been borrowed once and I cannot borrow them a second time?

Here is the snippet of code and its error:

```
fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) -> io::Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>>
where P: AsRef<Path> {
    let file = File::open(filename)
        .expect("Could not open word list.");
    Ok(io::BufReader::new(file)
        .lines())
}

fn compound_multiple(word_list: &Vec<String>) {
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(10);
    if let Ok(lines) = read_lines(word_list[0].as_str()) {
        for line in lines {
            if let Ok(word) = line {
                if let Ok(lines2) = read_lines(word_list[1].as_str()) {
                    for (counter, line2) in lines2.enumerate() {
                        if let Ok(word2) = line2 {
                            pool.execute(move || {
                                println!("{:?}{:?}{:?}", word, word2, counter + 1);
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `word`
   --> src/utils/fuzzer.rs:122:42
    |
118 |             if let Ok(word) = line {
    |                       ----
    |                       |
    |                       this reinitialization might get skipped
    |                       move occurs because `word` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
122 |                             pool.execute(move || {
    |                                          ^^^^^^^ value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
123 |                                 println!("{:?}{:?}{:?}", word, word2, counter + 1);
    |                                                          ---- use occurs due to use in closure

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

I have attempted to `clone()` the words on each iteration, but it produces the same error message.

I have tried:

```
    let word_list_one = File::open(word_list[0]).unwrap();
    let mut reader_one = BufReader::new(word_list_one); 
    let word_list_two = File::open(word_list[1]).unwrap();
    let mut reader_two = BufReader::new(word_list_two);
    for line_one in reader_one.by_ref().lines() {
        let line_one = line_one.unwrap().clone();
        for (counter, line_two) in reader_two.by_ref().lines().enumerate() {
            let line_two = line_two.unwrap().clone();
            pool.execute(move || {
               println!("{:?}{:?}{:?}", line_one, line_two, counter + 1);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried the suggestion from this Stack question --> [Trying to iterate 2 files in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67154863/trying-to-iterate-2-files-in-rust)

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried cloning `line_one` within the inner loop?  (Better yet, use `Arc<str>`).

Comment: Hey thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately, Arc<str> produces the same error on the lower version. "Arc<str> does not implement the Copy trait".

Comment: Oh yeah I wanted to help learn Rust by building a project that I would actually use. So its more of a learning thing than an actual work-related project. But yes, it has to be Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I made your code a little more readable. You may want to go further and use [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then) a few times, or change the return type of the function and use `?`.

```rs
pub fn compound_multiple(word_list: &Vec<String>) {
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(10);
    let Ok(lines) = read_lines(word_list[0].as_str()) else {
        return;
    };

    for line in lines {
        let Ok(word) = line else { return };
        let Ok(lines2) = read_lines(word_list[1].as_str()) else {
            return;
        };

        for (counter, line2) in lines2.enumerate() {
            let Ok(word2) = line2 else { return };

            pool.execute(move || {
                println!("{:?}{:?}{:?}", word, word2, counter + 1);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the solution. You need to make another clone for every closure you move. That means cloning in the inner loop.

```rs
pub fn compound_multiple(word_list: &Vec<String>) {
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(10);
    let Ok(lines) = read_lines(word_list[0].as_str()) else {
        return;
    };

    for line in lines {
        let Ok(word) = line else { return };
        let Ok(lines2) = read_lines(word_list[1].as_str()) else {
            return;
        };

        for (counter, line2) in lines2.enumerate() {
            let Ok(word2) = line2 else { return };
            let word = word.clone();

            pool.execute(move || {
                println!("{:?}{:?}{:?}", word, word2, counter + 1);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If all you need is read-only access to the strings, then you can use [`Arc<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), which allows you to keep only one copy of each word from the first word list in memory, instead of making a separate copy for every word in the second word list. You can use this in the same way you use `&str`, and it will free the memory when the last clone is dropped. If you need to explicitly coerce `Arc<str>` to `&str`, you can dereference it, like `&*word`. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4df945be762c4413ff50213dc851a387)

```rs
pub fn compound_multiple(word_list: &Vec<String>) {
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(10);
    let Ok(lines) = read_lines(word_list[0].as_str()) else {
        return;
    };

    for line in lines {
        let Ok(word) = line else { return };
        let Ok(lines2) = read_lines(word_list[1].as_str()) else {
            return;
        };

        let word: Arc<str> = word.into();

        for (counter, line2) in lines2.enumerate() {
            let Ok(word2) = line2 else { return };
            let word = word.clone();

            pool.execute(move || {
                println!("{:?}{:?}{:?}", word, word2, counter + 1);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello drewtato, thank you for this, works like a charm. Now I need to figure out how to push these words to a function call. Which currently is giving me the error from before. Seems when I print the items it works without issue, but assuming passing the ownership over to the function takes me back to step 1 =(. Here is a [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=75832e23a95e2f094f3b4bec56c72a40) of what I currently have.

Comment: @AndrewMcKenzie I'm gonna guess you need to change `execute` to take `FnOnce` instead of `Fn` or `FnMut`.